# template function overloading with template type-parameter-list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overload-resolution

Please help to understand below 3 different syntax's

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Demo {
public:
   void print_type(){
        if(is_same<int,T>())
                cout << "Int type" << endl;
        if(is_same<float,T>())
                cout << "float type" << endl;

    }
 };

//1.   fun
template<typename T>   
void fun(Demo<T> a){
    cout << "In <T>fun(Demo<T>)" <<endl;
    a.print_type();
}

//2. fun
template<typename T=int,class D=Demo<T> >
void fun(D a){
    cout << "In <T,class>fun(Demo)" <<endl;
    a.print_type();
}
// 3. fun
template<typename T=int,template <typename T> class D=Demo >
void fun(D<T> a){
    cout << "In <T,template>fun(Demo<T>)" <<endl;
}
int main()
{
   fun(Demo<int>());
   fun(Demo<float>());
   return 0;
}
```

1. the function calls in `main` are calling the first version of `fun`
2. if I comment out any two definitions of `fun`, the third one is called

What is the difference between the three `fun` definitions? How can I call all 3 without commenting out any of them?

Comment: what exactly do you want to be able to do? you want to somehow disambiguate these definitions? what exactly does it mean "call 3 functions without commenting them?"

Comment: @Chris Beck I want to disambiguate these 3 functions and want to understand the difference between them

Comment: Did you try compiling before posting the code? `print_type` is `private`, once I fix that, I don't have to comment anything out. So I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Praetorian sorry it's typo mistake,  try executing the above with below test cases
1. don't comment any function 
2. comment 1 fun and run
3. comment 1,2 and run

Comment: Okay, I think you're asking about *partial ordering of function templates*, you should be able to find more information about that on SO. The reason for 1. is that the first version of `fun` is the most specialized for the arguments you're passing in `main`. You can call the other versions by either explicitly specifying the template arguments, or by using different types - [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e406a86df64b4118)

Comment: My guess is that the compiler determines that it doesn't need to compile fun2 or fun3, so it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at our three functions:

```
template <typename T> void fun(Demo<T> );                           // (1)
template <typename T, typename D> void fun(D );                     // (2)
template <typename T, template <typename> class D> void fun(D<T> ); // (3)
```

Let's consider the second. `D` will be deduced from the first argument, but `T` does not appear in any of the function parameters - it is a *non-deduced context*. As such, it must be specified explicitly by the caller in order to be considered. You do not specify it, so it's a deduction failure and is thrown out of the overload set.

Now (1) and (3) are both viable candidates for arguments of type `Demo<int>` and `Demo<float>`. In both cases, the two functions take identical arguments that are exact matches for the caller and are both function templates - so the last tiebreaker is to consider which function template is *more specialized* (this is also called function template partial ordering). (1) can *only* accept types that look like `Demo<T>`. (3) can accept `Demo<T>` but also `OtherTemplate<T>` or `YetAnotherClass<T>`. It's more generic - so we prefer to call (1). The rules for this are pretty complicated, but you can do more searching if you're interested. A simpler example might be:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T );  // (4)
template <typename T> void foo(T* ); // (5)
foo(new int(42));
```

Both candidates are viable, (4) matches with `T = int*` and (5) matches with `T = int`. But (4) matches *anything* whereas (5) only matches pointers, which makes it more specialized and thus the best viable candidate.

If you comment out (2), nothing changes - it wasn't a viable candidate anyway. But if you comment out (1), then we call (3) because (3) becomes the only viable candidate (and thus, trivially, the best viable candidate).